# How to SQL query last inserted row group

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

i am try to sql query like that: (maybe it is simple, i am new learner)

```
tableA
---------------------------------------
id ------ name ----- score--hit--date
1784---- PlayerA ----- 20----9---20.05.2014
1793---- PlayerB ----- 18----5---20.05.2014
1792---- Playerc ----- 16----2---20.05.2014
1791---- PlayerD ----- 10----0---20.05.2014
1790---- PlayerG ----- 20----7---19.05.2014
1789---- PlayerO ----- 12----6---19.05.2014
1788---- PlayerT ----- 9-----8---19.05.2014
1787---- PlayerZ ----- 7-----0---19.05.2014
```

i want to this :

```
--TODAYS-BEST SCORERS-
name ----- score--hit
PlayerA --- 20-----9
PlayerB ----18-----5
Playerc --- 16-----2
PlayerD --  10-----0
```

and

```
-YESTERDAYS-BEST SCORERS-
name -------- score--hit
PlayerG ------ 20-----7
PlayerO -------12-----6
PlayerT ------ 9------8
PlayerZ -----  7------0
```

Row counts all day changes, not static value. Yesterday 20 rows inserted, but today 12 rows insterted.

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: And can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: mysql server... i tried lost of queries. i start to try 4 hour ago. i tried again and again.. it is very simple i think but i miss that.

Comment: SELECT id,name,score,hit,date FROM tableA WHERE date LIKE "20.05.2014" Order By Score Desc

Comment: You should have a look at the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Especially at the functions `CURDATE()` and `DATE_ADD()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the records of today:

```
SELECT name, score, hit 
FROM tableA 
WHERE date = CURDATE()
```

For the records of yesterday:

```
SELECT name, score, hit 
FROM tableA  
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

In case you want the last day instead of today, note that this only works in case you stored the date correctly as a `DATE`-type ([example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04003/1/0)):

```
SELECT name, score, hit 
FROM tableA 
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableA)
```

In case you want the second to last day that's not necessarilly consequetive ([example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04003/7/0)):

```
SELECT name, score, hit 
FROM tableA 
WHERE date = (
    SELECT date 
    FROM tableA  
    GROUP BY date  
    ORDER BY date DESC  
    LIMIT 1,1
)
```

*What does this subquery do?* It groups all dates, so instead of five records with dates (in the example) you'll have two records. Next it sorts these records by date in a descending order, hence the `DESC`. This means you'll have the first record with the 20th, the second with the 17th and any other dates following. Next it selects only the second record (so the second to last day) with the `LIMIT`.

The main query only retreives records matching this day, that would be the 17th in the example.

Comment: i dont need time based query, i want last days query. some days no items insterted for 5-6 days.

today is 20.05.2014 but next data come time 25.05.2014

Comment: @user2796291 I've extended the answer.

Comment: thx Aquillo, but my problem continues, think that : today is 23.05.2014 and last data date is 20.05.2014. if today no have data, it must shows last data

Comment: @user2796291 In that case all records from `20.04.2014` will be retreived using the last provided query. The subquery takes the last date and the main query will take only the records matching this selected last date.

Comment: @user2796291 I've added an example for the last query.

Comment: ok. i did it. first i changed to data writing format and it ok now. but how to i find "max(date)" 1 day before ? (not really a 1 day, 1 before data)

Comment: oh my poor brain. i did it. very very thanx Aquillo.

Comment: You're welcome, I've just extended the question a bit. Maybe it'll help you in the future ;)